# Is there is any replacement of $('#div_id').load(page_url); in angularjs, because after reload that page in div angularjs is not working

Tags: angularjs

In my main page there is a `div id="page_content"`, i load a jsp page in that div. and there is a refresh button ,through which the page is reloaded in that div. i have written some angularjs like `{{1+2}}` on that page. first it run properly displaying result 3. but when refresh button is clicked calling `$('#page_content').load(page_url);` page is refreshed but my angularjs func gone and it displayed `{{1+2}}`. how to overcome through this?

i tried route functionality but it dosen't work

```
angular.module('div', [])
.controller('divcontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope,$location)
{
    $scope.ConfirmRefresh = function(){   
        $('#page_content').load(page_url);
    }
}]);


angular.element(function()
{
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['div']);
});
```

after refresh button is clicked page should be loaded with angular js .

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29223437/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you @Mark Schultheiss and @Tom Edwards 

I make refresh directive and call on click event with compile and it works for me

.directive('refreshConfirm', function($http,$compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function () {

                    $http.get(page_url).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
                    function successCallback(response){
                        //success code
                        var ty=response.data;
                        var appi=angular.element(document.querySelector('#page_content')).html($compile(ty)(scope));
                    }
                    function errorCallback(error){
                        //error code
                        alert('error');
                    }                       

                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with the function caching data for when its called the next time, however it caches the code not the resulting code.

Consider using :
`$window.location.reload()`

this should refresh the page completely

Comment: `.load(url)` is not the same as reloading the entire page http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: but reloading the entire page will work, he hasn't specified that he cannot do this?